# What's causing this exception? Using VC++ 2010 with libcurl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, libcurl

I'm using libcurl in VC++ 2010 and getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Fourth.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
std::string DownloadFile(std::string Fname, std::string Furl)
{
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        const char *url = Furl.c_str();
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            FILE * pFile;
            pFile = fopen(Fname.c_str(),"wb");
            if (pFile!=NULL) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pFile);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
                char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                std::string xres = curl_easy_strerror(res); //// HERE ////
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                fclose(pFile);
                return xres;
            }
        }
}
```

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x86c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> First-chance exception at 0x77a6d968 (ntdll.dll) in Fourth.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Fourth.exe
>
> 'Fourth.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Exports
>   loaded.
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Fourth.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x148c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x170c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'Main Thread' (0x83c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1174) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xc74) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[1232] Fourth.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[1232] Fourth.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with
>   code 0 (0x0).

Might it have something to do with the \SysWOW64\ DLL's and the Win32 thread conflicting?

Comment: Please a compilable example where the error occurs. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it occurs on this line "std::string xres = curl_easy_strerror(res);"

Comment: Repeat: `Please a compilable example where the error occurs. stackoverflow.com/help/mcve` . Other than that, some code paths have no `return`, that's UB.

Comment: What is `res` set to prior to the crash?

Comment: res is null, only defined

Comment: weird thing, I copied and pasted only this part of the code to another new project, leaving out all the other pieces, and it works fine by itself... going to add piece by piece to see what's conflicing

Comment: Now you know why I asked you for a compilable example where the problem occurs...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the /MDd switch to /MD and it cleared up that problem, but not without adding some others!

Comment: Because something in your code is wrong, but you won't show it to us. UB is mean, but changing compiler switches is not the solution.

Comment: Well, my code is for retail cryptographic application, and I can't share the lion's share of it... just needed help on a specific error, thanks! And that was the problem, because the cURL library seems to need to be compiled with the /MD switch and not the /MDd, just letting others know who are using cURL to use /MD